# Change tab page to iFrame

Tags: iframe, fbml, facebook-apps

I have an old Facebook app that installs on Facebook Pages. The tab page is not being hosted in an iframe, but instead Facebook is embedding the HTML into their website (I think this is called FBML). How do I change the tab to be hosted in an iFrame like the new Apps do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, to change your tab to work as an iFrame instead of embedded HTML, you have to go to your app settings - advanced and under Migration enable Page Tab iFrames.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive what you are referring to is one of the old "static FBML" applications that used to be around.

> ...tab page is not being hosted in an iframe, but instead Facebook is embedding the HTML into their website...

It would let you paste your FBML (Facebook Markup Language) code into a textarea in the settings of the static FBML app.

This is no longer a feasible option as Facebook has deprecated and is [in the process of removing FBML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).

> FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed...

What I believe you'll have to do is re-write your application utilizing the newer [JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)/[PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) SDK's (or any of the [other non-official SDK's](https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+SDK) that are out there).  You'll have to [create a new app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) of [your very own](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34155/jonas-stawski) and then add it to your pages.

Comment: I'm not talking about those old apps that let me paste FBML. If you go here: http://www.facebook.com/DISolutions/app_389845102120 there's the app and you'll notice that the HTML is embedded into Facebook.com. This other app, http://www.facebook.com/DISolutions/app_363004220385602, in the other hand, includes an iFrame.

Comment: Creating a new app is not an option as I have clients already using the current one.

Comment: Are both those apps administered by you? Also, how old is **old**?

Comment: yes, they are both administered by me. The app in questioned is at least 2 years old, while the other is about a week old.

Comment: Where is the actual code sitting?  Where do you edit the content of that [first app](https://www.facebook.com/DISolutions/app_389845102120)? Also - is it listed for you at https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: the code lives in our servers. FB is making a request from their servers to our servers and embedding the HTML. The app is listed on the dev portal (or whatever is called)

Comment: Have you gone through the settings of the application in all the tabs? Maybe there is a radio button tucked in there somewhere :P (I don't have any apps that old so I'm not sure if the UI is the same).  This is quite weird behavior in my experience and it hints towards some major differences between newer and older apps.  Things have changed A LOT in 2 years...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8680/discussion-between-lix-and-jonas-stawski)

Comment: Here's the main problem. I used to get the page id like so: Request["fb_sig_page_id"]. But recently that has been null. So i tried to decoding the signed_request and the page object within the JSON is also blank. So I figured that if I'm able to change the tab to display in an iFrame the page.id will now be populated. Unless I can do that by turning a setting on my app.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<style>
  img {
    background-color: ;
    url("house.png");
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  
  #bars {
    background-color: ;
    margin-right: px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    url("bars.jpg");
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  #name {
    background-color: ;
    font-size: 160px;
    hieght: 120px;
    width: 750px;
    color: hotpink;
    text-shadow: 5px 7px 4px silver;
    font-family: "sofia", sans-serif;
    z-index: +20;
    margin-left: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  #welcom {
    hieght: auto;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: ;
    letter-spacing: 70px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  #content {
    background-color: ;
    height: autor;
    width: autor;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .pic {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1340px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  }
  
  #facebook3 {
    margin-rigth: 300px;
    url("facebook3.png");
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  
  #massange {
    margin-left: 0px;
    url("massange.png");
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  
  #whatsapp2 {
    url("whatsapp2.png");
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  
  .sociol {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 450px;
    url("facebook3.png");
  }
  
  .socio1 {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-lef: 800px;
  }
  
  .socio2 {
    background-color: green;
    margin-lef: 200px;
  }
  
  #ceo {
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  #pic1 {
    background-color: ;
    height: 350px;
    width: autor;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  .footer {
    background-color: ;
    height: 900px;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  }
  
  h2 {
    background-color: hotpink;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  #social {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100px;
    widht: autor;
  }
  
  .footer a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: black;
  }
  
  ul li {
    margin: left: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #back {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 200px;
    width: autor;
  }
  
  .span {
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 120px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: +20;
    margin-left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relatie;
    desplay: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1330px;
    height: 1900px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin: 50px;
    z-index: +20;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: silver;
    z-index: +20;
    width: 200xp;
    height: 140px;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .advert {
    background-color: ;
    margin-rigth: 1500px;
    color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .icons {
    background-color: red;
    margin-rigth: 70px;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #pro {
    background-color: hotpink;
    color: grey;
    height: 40px;
    width: autor;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  address {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #copy {
    color: silver;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #andyazi {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
  
  p {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
  
  p3 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
  
  #ceo {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <!--STAGE1-->

  <div id=body>
    <div id=container>
      <div id=board>
        <div id=bars>
          <div class="dropdown"><img src="house.png">
            <di class="span">
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"><img src="sign in.png"> SIGN IN
                  <a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="service.png"> SERVICES
                      <a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="about2.png"> ABOUT
                          <a>
                            <a href="contac1t.html"><img src="contact.png"> CONTACT US</a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="sign up.png"> SIGN UP
                              <a>
                                <a href="help.html"><img src="help.png"> HELP</a>
                                <a href="downloads.html"><img src="new jobs.png"> JOBS</a>
                                <a href="buy.html"><img src="buy.png"> BUY</a>
                                <a href="ixesha2.html"><img src="time2.png"> S-HOURS
                                  <a>
                                    </span>
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id=name>BEAUTSILVER</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--STAGE2-->
    <div id=content>
      <div id=welcom><i>ESTIATORIO.</i></div>

      <div id=picture><img src="loogo.jpg" class="pic"></div>
    </div>

    <div id=ceo>CEO AND FOUNDER
      <BR>MR Funde Mthetheleli</div>
    <div id=pro>
      <p3>OUR PRODUCTS</p3>
    </div>

    </p7>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class=icons<img src="facebook3.png" class="socio1"><img src="buy.png" class="sociol"><img src="call us.png" class="call"><img src="email.png" class="email"><img src="whatsapp.png" class="socio2"><img src="tweeter.png" class="socio2">
    <div class=advert>JOIN US ON SOCIAL PLATFORMS</div>
  </div>
  <div class=footer>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="sign in.html"><img src="press.png"> PRESS ROOM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="teams.html"><img src="gift.png"> GIFT CERTIFICATES<br>&COOKBOOK</a>
      </li><br>
      <li>
        <a href="contacts.html"><img src="contacts.png"> CONTACTS US</a>
      </li><br>
    </ul>

    <div id=andyazi>BEAUTSILVER | AVVIA</div>





    <div id=address>71PHALO STREET<br>MOTHERWELL<br>PORT ELIZABETH<br>6211</div>
    <h2>RESEVATIONS & HOURS<br> DIRECTIONS
    </h2>



  </div>
  </div>
  <div id=copy><i>copyrigth &copy: funde mthetheleli</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]